# Can I travel to US with B1/B2 visa and still continue to work remotely for my local employer (like work from remote area set-up) for 4-6 months?

Tags: visas, usa, work

I will travel in the USA for a period of 4 - 6 months, but I will continue to do time working for my current employer (remote work set-up) and getting paid by the local (non-US) employer. Would there be any concerns under a tourist/business visa (B1/B2)? Thank you.